# What is the best way to open html files from vscode when using WSL?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Specifically, I am using the open-in-browser extension, but when I go to open my html for a given project it fails to load in the browser. I have tried putting my repo in both a straight Linux directory as well as in a folder in c/mnt/Users... Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After stumbling on the same issue I found a straightforward extension to solve the issue: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=peakchen90.open-html-in-browser

This extension does not serve the file from the filesystem, but rather serves it from a local webserver.

I was rather looking for something that would convert the WSL filepath into the corresponding windows filepath, but this works just as well if not better, for webdev purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Also another option as this did not work for me:

In WSL (I'm using WSL2) run a simple HTTP-server, e.g. using:

```bash
cd path/to/your/file
python3 -m http.server 5000
```

This allows you to connect to the localhost in WSL at port 5000 from your Windows-system via your browser and simply open the .html-file there (even allowing all JavaScript or whatever to be executed correctly).

Note: Be reminded that you cannot run `localhost` in your Windows-browser but need to resolve to the IP-address which WSL opens for this.
You can find the IP-address when running `ip route` in WSL and look for the "link src", e.g. something like `172.XX.XXX.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.XX.XXX.XX`. This example would require you to open `172.XX.XXX.XX:5000` in your Windows browser.